# Mysterious mixed content warning - it appears to all be https with no http?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, https, shadowbox

I have an https page which launches a shadowbox which itself has a page inside it.  The shadowbox content is got with whatever protocol the parent page is, so loads with https as well.

When the shadowbox page loads I get a mixed content warning, saying that some parts are not encrypted.  Usually this happens when some of the page contents are got with https requests and some with http.  However, according to the "Live HTTP Headers" plugin for firefox, every header for the parent page and the page loaded into the shadowbox are all https: there's no sign of an http request anywhere.

I'm a bit stumped by this and want to get rid of the mixed content warning, because they're really intrusive in some browsers and generally make people panic a bit.

Can anyone else suggest why this might be happening, or a way to diagnose it further?
Grateful for any advice -  max

Comment: Have you tried to see what's going on with another plugin (e.g. HttpFox or Firebug)?

Comment: I seemingly have the same problem, did you find a fix for this ?

Comment: I did find the problem: there was some javascript running after page load that was pulling in some external resource (from fastfonts as it happens) and this was causing the mixed content warning.  If it's happening for you still, try switching off javascript in your browser and see if it still happens.  I didn't find a satisfactory way to debug this: the net tab in firebug only lists resources loaded by the page itself, rather than after page load.